# Youtube API Sever Side key not working on subdomains

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api, ip

I have a site that uses the Youtube API and we use a server API key which uses IP's as the allowed locations to get the information.

When used locally things work fine. I have a simple server running on my computer and getting the ip from http://who.is/ allows me to get the video information.

However when the application is set up on a url that is a subdomain say `dev.site.com` for development purposes, I am not getting any information.

If I who.id the subdomain the IP constantly changes. If I `dig` the server I get a stable IP but this does not seem to solve the issue.

Has anyone else encountered a situation like this? Is there a step I am missing?

Comment: I'm not sure where you're hosting the app, but if the IP "constantly changes" you'll not be able to keep the list of allowed IPs correct. This isn't a programming issue, so it's more suited to http://serverfault.com

Comment: @ViniciusPinto Well the static server IP stays the same, but the subdomain IP changes. But you are correct, I will check with the clients server admin to see if there is an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved this myself. After trying many different IPs for the server, I just removed all the IP's associated to the server key.

And that seemed to fix it, I am still unsure why adding the IP for the server did not work. Which is quite frustrating.